# Adding data from text file into prepared Word table

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad

I have text file with content as follows:

```
something1
something2
something3
...
```

I want to copy it to preexisting table in Word. I mean 1 row from .txt file translates to 1 cell in Word. Copying one by one is very tedious. I don't want to have 1 cell with total list of "somethings". Cheers

Comment: Best way I could suggest is to copy it to Excel first, then copy that to Word.

Comment: It still creates 1 cell with all data of "somethings".

Answer (score 3):

Word has an option for taking lists of text and converting them to tables. Start by pasting your data into Word, then highlight everything you want to be a table.  Go to the **Insert** tab, click the down arrow on **Table** and select the **Convert Text to Table...** option.

[image]

After you select this, you will be presented with an options window:

[image]

If your data came from a comma separated or tab delimited file, you can use the **Separate text at** options here to break it into columns.  In the case of your sample data, only one column is required, so the number of columns remains at 1.  Hit **OK** and your text will become a full-fledged table, not a single cell with a list in it.